# Convert HTML to PDF with Special Characters using Java

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer, html-to-pdf

I am using [flying saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) with **iText 2.1.7** for converting `html to pdf`. It works fine, but the problem occurs when there are some chinese, korean, etc characters in the html.

I get unexpected characters in my PDF instead of the normal chinese characters

I found [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/issues/detail?id=211) opened, so I assume there is currently no way of making flying saucer into rendering the PDF correctly?

PS: I also found [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/issues/detail?id=91), but I can't understand the solution they have provided.

This is the code that I am using

```
String doc = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont (
    "C:\\ARIALUNI.TTF",
     BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
     BaseFont.EMBEDDED
);
renderer.setDocument(doc);
String outputFile = "report.pdf";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Where **file** is the html which I am trying to convert.

Is there some other way or library to do the same?

This is the css that i am using

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Arial";
  src: url("media/arialuni.ttf");
 -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
 -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H; 
}
```

The [HTML file](https://gist.github.com/4109733) that I need to convert

[These](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/flying%20saurcer%20jars.rar) are the re-compiled flying saucer jar compatible with itext 2.1..x

Comment: try, how? how to pass UTF-16 to flying saucer

Comment: Which problem occurs? Do you get an exception, or do you get unexpected characters in your PDF?

Comment: I get unexpected characters in my PDF instead of the normal chinese characters

Comment: According to your last issue solution, looks like this is a font problem!

Comment: Have you tried what's being said in the second link: `renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("yourFont-unicode-ready.ttf",
"UTF-8", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);` ?

Comment: @Alex yes I tried that, but still it doesn't embed my font in the pdf. I have updated the code that I use

Comment: In the last post at the forum, that is probably why they "edit" the css before rendering PDF.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie I tried both, I have updated the css that i used

Comment: Can you post the link of the website that is translated to PDF ?

Comment: It is a secured site and I need to convert a  report which I have as html(generated on the fly)

Comment: Can you post the FlyingSaucer code so I could start from it to test? (your complete test class)

Comment: Perfect, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your font is probably not embedded in the PDF file. ( [How do I know if the fonts in a PDF file are embedded or not?](https://superuser.com/questions/140613/how-do-i-know-if-the-fonts-in-a-pdf-file-are-embedded-or-not) )

Every font has a name, ARIALUNI.TTF defines Arial Unicode MS, you should use that.

So change this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Arial1;
    src: url("arialuni.ttf");
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

* {
        font-family: Arial1;
}
```

To this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
    src: url("arialuni.ttf");
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

* {
        font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
}
```

This way the font will be embedded.

And you don't need to call `renderer.getFontResolver().addFont`, the css is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`font.addFont(Html2Pdfs.class.getResource("SIMSUN.TTC").toString().substring(6),BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)`

Comment: Hi this is not working. Is Html2Pdfs some special class, do you have a working code that you can share?